# angularjs-- declenching events

Tags: angularjs

Please, how can I change this code into angularJs

```
$('a.product_add').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var collectionHolder = $('#task_tags');
    var prototype = collectionHolder.attr('data-prototype');
    form = prototype.replace(/__name__/g, collectionHolder.children().length);
    collectionHolder.append(form);
});
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a code-conversion service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to show us what you've tried, but I'll write something here to help you

You  should make a directive because you're using `jquery` code. Read more about directives [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

> AngularJS directives are extended HTML attributes with the prefix ng-.
>
> The ng-app directive initializes an AngularJS application.
>
> The ng-init directive initializes application data.
>
> The ng-model directive binds the value of HTML controls (input,
>   select, textarea) to application data.

Example of a directive

```
  app.directive('myDirective', function(){
    function link($scope,$elem,$attrs){

       $elem.on('click', function(event){
           // click event code here
       });

    }
    return { 
      link:link,
      scope:{},
      restrict:'A'
     }
  })
```

Example of usage  for `myDirective`:

```
<a class='product_add' my-directive>link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use angular custom directives.
Now you can access the element in the directive and do the same operations in the directive.
`<directive-element ng-click=appendFunction()></directive-element>`